# Show that free group $\mathbb{F}_2$ is not amenable using Hulanicki-Reiter condition.

Tags: group-theory, metric-spaces, amenability

Hulanicki-Reiter condition states:

A finetely generated group G is amenable if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$ and $R>0$ there exists a function $f\in l_1(G)_{1,+}$ such that:

a) $||f-\gamma f||_1<\epsilon$ for all $\gamma\in G$ when $|\gamma|\leq R$

b) $\text{supp}f$ is finite

where $l_1(G)_{1,+}=\{f\in l_1(G):||f||_1=1\text{ and }f\geq 0$

Using this condition show that free group $\mathbb{F}_2$ is not amenable.

I only know proof of nonamenability of free group by use of invariant mean, but I heard that there is somewhere proof of this fact which only uses Hulanicki-Reiter condition, but I neither can find it nor prove it by myself.

Comment: Letting $R$ tend to $\infty$ and $\varepsilon$ tend to zero, and choosing a limit point, you get an invariant mean. Anyway, since the negation of the statement says that there exist $\varepsilon$ and $R$ you can ask for a quantitative statement (actually one can choose $R=1$); this should be classical in functional analysis (and is called an isoperimetric inequality).